# Como ter acesso ao diretório raiz var/www/ de um container docker atraves do browser do host?

Tags: docker

Estou iniciando em docker.

Criei uma imagem com o seguinte comando

```
docker run -ti -p 80:80 my-image
```

Essa imagem é um ubuntu:14.04 onde eu instalei apache e php5.
Verifiquei na raiz `/var/www` e a página index está lá e o php tbm instalado `php -v`.

Meu host é ubuntu 16.04.
Verifiquei o ip do docker através de ifconfig e tenho `docker0 inet addr:172.17.0.1`.

Usando o browser do meu host faço 172.17.0.1:80 e tenho a mensagem "The connection was reset".

EU estava esperando ver a página inicial do apache.

Como resolver isso?

Comment: `172.17.0.1` deve ser o IP da _docker machine_, não? Veja o IP do container com `docker inspect <seu_container> | awk '/IPAddress/ || /HostPort/'`, ou então apenas `docker inspect <seu_container>` e procure por `IPAddress`